# How to make search option to filter out data which i already pulled out of database

Tags: android, mysql, listview

Greet sir, I'm new in Android programming. I have a task that I need to retrieve data from MYSql and make a search functionality to the data that I retrieve before.

My problem is I can't make a search functionality on the data that I pull from MYSql to listview, I tried google but most of them already make the data as default like this.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

final ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
data.add("apple");
data.add("banana");
data.add("grape");
data.add("orange");
data.add("pear");
data.add("peach");
data.add("tomato");

ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.item, R.id.itemName, data);

setListAdapter(dataAdapter);
getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}
```

this is the code that I referred to make a search functionality

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtsearch);
    initList();
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int
                after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int
                count) {
            if(s.toString().equals("")){
                // reset listview
                initList();
            } else {
                // perform search
                searchItem(s.toString());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
}
public void searchItem(String textToSearch){
    for(String item:items){
        if(!item.contains(textToSearch)){
            listItems.remove(item);
        }
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public void initList(){
    items=new String[]{"Canada","China","Japan","USA"};
    listItems=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.list_item, R.id.txtitem, listItems);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and this is how I pull data from MYSql to listview.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_retrieve_data);

    listview = (Listview)findViewById(R.id.ListView1)
    new RetrieveTask().execute();

}

@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try{
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exceptionMessage+", Ex1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
            result = sb.toString();
            System.out.println("-----JSON Data-----");
            System.out.println(result);
            is.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exceptionMessage+", Ex2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }try{
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            int totalCount = jsonArray.length();
            for(int i=0; i<totalCount; i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                names += jsonObject.getString("name")+":";
                emails += jsonObject.getString("email")+":";
                phones += jsonObject.getString("phone")+":";
                combinedText += (i+1)+". Name '"+jsonObject.getString("name")+"', "+
                        "Email '"+jsonObject.getString("email")+"', "+
                        "Phone '"+jsonObject.getString("phone")+"':";
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exceptionMessage+", Ex3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        name = names.split(":");
        email = emails.split(":");
        phone = phones.split(":");
        combinedArray = combinedText.split(":");
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(RetrieveData.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, combinedArray));
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

This is the output of the data but is it possible to make a filtering on the listview using 'edie' by `EditText`from the all of list of data that I pull from MYSQL?

[image]

Comment: Please upload the result image here itself, in case external link goes down  in future

Comment: I think you can create one custom adapter through which you can able to search contents.

Comment: @RanjitPati sir, can you explain more deeper by 'custom adapter' ?

Comment: do you have knowledge about `BaseAdapter` ?

Comment: @RanjitPati An adapter is used to bind data to a view? I'm not quiet with that thing sir.